# Pull data from one sheet to the next empty row of another sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to pull data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 based on a criteria and a cell value where x rows are only copied when `[Qualification] = 'Qualified'` and, if `[No of positions] = x`.
If x= 1, specific columns are copied once to Sheet 2. If x = 2, specific columns are copied twice to Sheet 2.

Below is an example.

**Sheet1**

| Lead Type | Lead ID | Company Name | Employment Type | No of positions | Qualification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| External | B21 | KidRed Co. | Full Time | 1 | Not Qualified |
| Africa | B24 | Freddie Co. | Part Time | 2 | Qualified |
| Base | B35 | Akila Co. | Full Time | 1 | Qualified |
| External | B40 | SeeQue Co. | Part Time | 1 | Not Qualified |

**Sheet2**

| Lead ID | Company Name | Qualification | Owner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B24 | Freddie Co. | Qualified | Sharon |
| B24 | Freddie Co. | Qualified | Sandra |
| B35 | Akila Co. | Qualified | Sheila |

I am currently running this query

```
function RepeatMatching(values, criterion = 'Qualified') {
  return values.flatMap(([, b, c, , e, f]) =>
    e > 0 && f == criterion ? [...Array(e)].fill([b, c, f]) : []
  );
}
;
```

And run `=RepeatMatching(Sheet1!A1:F, "Qualified")` in Sheet2

However, when [No of Positions] = x changes from 2 to 1, there is a mismatch with the Owner.
Is it possible to delete a whole row or add a whole row when there is a change in x?

Comment: @lamblichus Kindly assist

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `However, when [No of Positions] = x changes from 2 to 1, there is a mismatch with the Owner. Is it possible to delete a whole row or add a whole row when there is a change in x?`. Can you please clarify what is the desired output?

Comment: `f` of `[b, c, f]` should be `Qualification` and where does `Owner` come from?

Comment: Are you trying to do a `VLOOKUP` in the Owner Column?

Comment: @lamblichus, The desired output is that once [No of Positions] is updated, a row is added and the columns b,c,f are copied from Sheet 1 to the first 3 columns on Sheet 2. A person then fills out the [Owner]. Sometimes however, the No of Positions either increases or reduces and therefore a mismatch happens with the [Owner]. I would like a row to be deleted or added whenever this happens.

Comment: @idfurw No, I am not. Please see my explanation above, I hope it makes it clearer. The [Owner] name is input manually.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically output **[Owner]** in Sheet2, you need to manage the master data of Owner (maybe **[Lead ID]** and **[Owner]**) in a separate sheet and do `ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(...))` in it.

---

Sheet3

| Lead ID | Owner |
| --- | --- |
| B24 | Sharon |
| B35 | Sheila |

Formula to put into D2 of Sheet2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,'Sheet3!A:B',2,FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

I don't think what you want to do is possible. Mixing data returned via formula with data entered manually is not a good idea.

#### Solution:

Nevertheless, I think this could be accomplished by using an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger. The `onEdit` function would do the following:

- Grab the source data from `Sheet1` whenever this data is manually edited.
- Get the current data in `Sheet2`, including `Owner` (in the sample above, this data is located on columns `A:E`).
- For each `Qualified` row in the source data, retrieve the `Owners` that already exist on `Sheet2` with the same `Lead ID` (I'm assuming here that `Lead ID` can be used to identify a source row).
- For each `Qualified` row in the source data, append a number of rows equal to `No of positions`, each with the corresponding `Owner`, if it exists.
- Clear the old range and copy the new values, using [clearContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) and [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

#### Code sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === "Sheet1" && range.getColumn() < 7 && range.getRow() > 1) { // Check edited range is source data
    const sourceValues = sheet.getRange("A2:F" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    const ss = e.source;
    const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    const targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
    let oldTargetValues = [];
    let oldTargetRange;
    if (targetLastRow > 1) {
      oldTargetRange = targetSheet.getRange("A2:E" + targetSheet.getLastRow());
      oldTargetValues = oldTargetRange.getValues(); // Get current data in Sheet2
    }
    const targetValues = sourceValues.reduce((acc, [, sourceLeadId, companyName, , numPositions, qualification]) => { // Iterate through source data to build new target data
      if (qualification === "Qualified") { // Grab only Qualified rows
        const currentOwners = oldTargetValues.filter(row => row[0] === sourceLeadId).map(row => row[3]); // Get owners related to current Lead ID
        for (let i = 0; i < numPositions; i++) { // Append source data "No of position" times
          const targetRow = [sourceLeadId, companyName, qualification];
          if (currentOwners[i]) targetRow.push(currentOwners[i]);
          else targetRow.push("");
          acc.push(targetRow);
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
    if (oldTargetRange) oldTargetRange.clearContent(); // Clear old target range
    targetSheet.getRange(2,1,targetValues.length, targetValues[0].length).setValues(targetValues); // Write new target data
  }
}
```